# Calculating corresponding calendar day of previous years

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, date

I have the following beast of an SQL (DB2) statement...

```
select ((date(days(date(cast(year('2012-03-28')-6 as char(4))|| '-01-01')) -(dayofweek(date(cast(year('2012-03-28')-6 as char(4))|| '-01-01') )-1))+7 days)+(((week('2012-03-28')-2)* 7)+dayofweek('2012-03-28')-1) days) AS CAL_COMP_DATE
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Taking the input date of Wednesday, 2012-03-28, this would return Wednesday, 2006-03-29. Notice that it matched the Thursdays. It matches the corresponding calendar day of previous years.

Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing the same goal in C# or VB.NET? I've tried translating this query into VB.NET, but haven't been able to do so perfectly and it just looks horrible and unmaintainable.

Comment: Like Daniel said, you haven't provided all the necessary logic.  Do you want to match based on the nth Wednesday of the calendar year?  or round to the nearest same weekday or some other rule?  You can probably modify what he provided to get to any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't completely understand the rule for finding that day. But you could use something along these lines:

```
var originalDate = new DateTime(2012,03,28);
var newDate = originalDate.AddYears(-6);
var daysToAdd = originalDate.DayOfWeek - newDate.DayOfWeek;
if(daysToAdd < -3)
    daysToAdd += 7;
if(daysToAdd > 3)
    daysToAdd -= 7;
newDate = newDate.AddDays(daysToAdd);
```

This always rounds to the nearest day with the same DayOfWeek.

Comment: `-5`, but yea very confused on what the output should be.

Comment: `-4` on purpose, because 2012-03-28 has the same DayOfWeek as 2007-03-28 and so I couldn't really test my logic for subtracting the days :-)

Comment: This seems to work so far... I tested all the way up to 2016. Would there be any weird "gotchas" for leap years or anything?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know the real logic you need. I suggest, you just try it. But I don't think so, because the AddYears method is really just adding the provided value to the year part of the date. After that, the DayOfWeek is checked and then the days are subtracted. Subtracting days is aware of leap days, so there really shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: It breaks down in some cases. For instance, given 2012-12-23 and going back 6 years, it gives back 2006-12-17, when it should actually be 2006-12-24.